# Background removal of gradient background

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to calculate the sum of intensities present in my agarose gel:

[image: Example of agarose gel]

I want to compare the intensity of the total white band on the top with that of the one on the bottom. 
The idea is to binarize the image at a certain threshold and use that matrix (the 1's) to determine the gray scale value at that same index in the original picture. However in order to properly binarize I want to substract the background. As seen over here there is a kind of gradient present. Do you guys have any ideas how to properly identify the background and substract it from the original image.

**EDIT:**

I now try to cut the image in two parts beforehand (top part and bottom part) then I can neglect the background in a certain way.
I use the following code to identify the bands with image

[image: Image_1]:

```
topintens = Import["Image_1"];
topintens = MedianFilter[topintens, 1];
imt = Binarize[TopHatTransform[topintens, 4.09], 0.013];
imtfil = DeleteSmallComponents[imt, 7]
```

However I then end up with not so smooth bands, I want to apply dilation/erosion in order to make neat bands however this does not work out for me yet:

[image: Output]

So tips are welcome

Comment: I don't think it's a question of definitions or identification. In my opinion, your picture simply does not have a uniform background. You can 1) take another picture; or 2) ignore the gradient artifact. It would also be helpful if you could express the procedure you described in *Mathematica* code and include it in your post.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for your response

Comment: Is there no other way for you to take a picture with better contrast during electrophoresis?

Comment: Well the quality of the gels is always different, this was actually a pretty good image. Therefore we are searching for image analysis tools to interpret our data better

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to apply a highpass filter, since what you want to remove is the slowly undulating background.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvRAc.png"];
imgHP = ImageAdjust[HighpassFilter[img, 0.05]]
```

[image]

then binarize:

```
Binarize[imgHP]
```

[image]

To follow your original idea of locating the background and subtracting it -- this can be approached with a lowpass filter, followed by taking the difference between the image and the lowpass-filtered version:

```
bg = LowpassFilter[img, 0.1];
ImageAdjust[ImageDifference[bg, img]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very helpful to apply a highpass filter

Comment: Can you make a mask from known data about geometrie/mechanical dimensions of the setup? That would be my Approach to be Independent of the Image Quality.